# how to access data on four custom ui table view cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have one ui table view controller, that has four custom cells, each one of them has a custom ui table view cell.

now let's say i have added some buttons to the third custom ui table view cell, and i want to when one button of them clicked to access data (such as labels) that are in the second custom ui table view cell.

how can i do that?

this is a one example of the third custom ui table view cell

```
class thirdCellc: UITableViewCell {


//here i want to access data that are in another custom ui table view cell

}
```

keep on mind that i have also a custom ui table view controller like this:

```
class PageTwoViewController: UITableViewController {
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let rowNumber = indexPath.row
        switch rowNumber {
        case RequestData.numberOfPeople.rawValue:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentefiers.numberOfPeopleCell.rawValue) as! NumberOfPeopleTableViewCell
            return cell
        case RequestData.dayOfMeal.rawValue :
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentefiers.dayCell.rawValue) as! DayTableViewCell
            return cell
        case RequestData.timeOfMeal.rawValue:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentefiers.timeCell.rawValue) as! TimeTableViewCell
            return cell
        case RequestData.preferences.rawValue:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentefiers.preferencesCell.rawValue) as! PreferencesTableViewCell
            return cell
        default:
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have 3 different classes for 3 different cells? You can make 1 class that acts on behalf of all the cells you have: example: 500. You just need to set the labels and buttons to do different things based on the cell's indexPath.row.

Comment: @lukesIvi I would agree with you if I had the same outlets in each cell. However, in my context, one cell contains date attributes, another one contains an image selector, and the third one contains three buttons to interact with bank account.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create an outlet from the tableView to the custom class, then you can write code as follows

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! //outlet you created

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath() //Get index Path of cell you want in tableView
    let cell = tableView.cellforRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! FirstCell //Or whatever the other cell class was.

    cell.textLabel.text //Now you have all the dot properties of whatever cell at indexPath you passed in.
```

Comment: This is a creative approach. I will try it. +1, I will update you if that approach works for me. Nevertheless, I will keep waiting for other users' opinions

Comment: I will note that you will cell will be nil unless your first couple of cells are created first, which I assumed they would be.

Comment: I didn't get you. Apologies. may you repeat please ?

Comment: If lets say cell 1 or cell 2 haven't been created on the tableView before you create cell 3, then the `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)` will return a nil cell.

Comment: This is how I'd go about it as well/what I was proposing. Your labels and buttons can change depending on what you need.

Comment: @MatthewLawrenceBailey Sarah can specify that in the `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return yourArray.count}`